# Using GET Method to Maintain Variables After Logging In

Tags: php

I am using a login system.  When I navigate to comments/index.php without logging in, some variables get passed along using the GET method just fine.  Then, if I log in while I am on this page, these variables disappear.  The variables that disappear are $submission, $submissionid, and $url.

I thought I could use the GET method to keep them live after logging in by appending `?submission='.$submission.'&submissionid='.$submissionid.'&url='.$url.'` to the URL of the login form action as seen below.  But the variables still disappeared after I made this addition.

The relevant code I am trying to use is below.

Any idea what I can do to make it do what I want?

Thanks in advance,

John

In comments/index.php:

```
 require_once "header.php"; 

 include "login.php";

 include "comments.php";
```

In login.php:

```
if (!isLoggedIn())
{

    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {

        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();
        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {

        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{

    show_userbox();
}
```

In comments.php:

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);
echo '<div class="subcommenttitle"><a href="http://www.'.$url.'">'.$submission.'</a></div>';




$submission = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submission']);
$submissionid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submissionid']);
```

The login function:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?submission='.$submission.'&submissionid='.$submissionid.'&url='.$url.'"> 

    <div class="usernameformtext"><label title="Username">Username: </label></div> 
    <div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></div> 


    <div class="passwordformtext"><label title="Password">Password: </label></div> 
    <div class="passwordformfield"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></div> 


    <div class="registertext"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/register.php" title="Register">Register</a></div> 
    <div class="lostpasswordtext"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></div> 

  <p class="loginbutton"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';


}
```

Comment: You should only use `mysql_real_escape_string` on data that's getting interpolated into an SQL query. `$url` gets interpolated into an HTML element, so you should sanitize it against HTML injection instead. Also, look up prepared statements (and PDO) as a simpler alternative to escaping SQL values.

Comment: When I fleshed out the example, the query string propagated just fine in Safari 4.0. There's something you're leaving out. What browser(s) did you test? Are you using any redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$submission` &c. are local to `show_loginform`. You either need to declare them [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) ([yech](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)), pass them as arguments to the function:

```
function show_loginform($submission, $submissionid, $url, $disabled = false) {
    ...

//login.php:
...
    // warning: vulnerable to injection attack.
    show_loginform($_GET['submission'], $_GET['submissionid'], $_GET['url']);
```

or do something like:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false) {
    // vulnerable to injection attacks
    ?><form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
    ...
```

The last is the cleanest and simplest, merely passing through the query string, rather than rebuilding it.

Comment: How could I "pass them as arguments to the function"?

Comment: @John: the same way you'd pass any value as an argument to a function. Answer updated.

Comment: OK, thanks... I tried doing a hidden POST method, but then it just made something else disappear.  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

User sessions...

```
<?php
session_start();


$result = checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

if($result) {
    unset($_POST['password']);
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
        $_POST[$k] = trim(strip_tags($v)); // Fix injection
    }
    $_SESSION = $_POST;
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true; // Changed the order to show authenticate
}
```

Comment: The `$_SESSION = $_POST;` line would overwrite the `$_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;` assignment you make. Might want to move that line down.

Comment: `$_SESSION = $_POST` should be removed entirely, as it creates an injection vulnerability. Also, sessions break REST architectures.

Comment: @awgy and @outis - Thanks. Made the edit. How does sessions break REST and where is REST mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The $_GET variables will only get passed to the first page so you need to manually pass them on. First check to see if the user is logged in. If they aren't, display the form. Then use the following:

```
$query = http_build_query($_GET)
```

This will build a query string out of the $_GET variables. Now in the action attribute for your form, put `./index.php?$query`.

This will make sure they are passed along after the user logs in.

Comment: He's basically doing this already, just without `http_build_query`.

Comment: No it looks to me like he is defining $submission, for example, in comments.php which he includes after login.php. Therefore, login.php cannot echo $submission into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Querystring: ?submission='.$submission.'&submissionid='.$submissionid.'&url='.$url.'

replace the $ sign before submission to an uppersand &.

You should check the above posts for injection vulnerabilities though.

Good luck